# JSON calculate total number of particular Array object and result grouping

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

I have the following JSON data output from firebug console and I am trying to count the total number of the second item "Open" and group the result by Team. I am pulling the data from our SharePoint list.

```
"d":
{
    "results":
    [
        {
            "__metadata":
            {
                "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(53)",
                "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(53)",
                "etag": ""18"",
            "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
        },
            "Team": "Team A",
            "taskStatus": "Open"
},
{
                "__metadata":
{
    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(54)",
    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(54)",
    "etag": ""97"",
    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
},
                "Team": "Team B",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
},
{
    "__metadata":
    {
        "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(82)",
        "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(82)",
        "etag": ""65"",
        "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
    },
    "Team": "Team B",
    "taskStatus": "Open"
},
{
                "__metadata":
{
    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(97)",
    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(97)",
    "etag": ""18"",
    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
},
                "Team": "Team C",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
},
{
    "__metadata":
    {
        "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(99)",
        "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(99)",
        "etag": ""8"",
        "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
    },
    "Team": "Team E",
    "taskStatus": "Open"
},
{
                "__metadata":
{
    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(106)",
    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(106)",
    "etag": ""44"",
    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
},
                "Team": "Team D",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
},
```

I have used the following JavaScript and I am getting only a value that is not correct. I only get 3, which is not correct. It should be 300 or more. For the sake of brevity I am only posting an excerpt of my JSON data.

```
// JavaScript source code
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items?$filter=taskStatus eq 'Open'&$select=Team,taskStatus",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: "true",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var dataArray = [];
        var countArray = [];
        var results = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            for (key in results[i]) {
                if (results[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    countArray.push(results[i][key]);             
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            var team = Object.keys(results[1]).length; //This is returning only the value of 3

            console.log(team);
        }
        console.log(countArray);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Can you please assist in solving this?

I have revised the raw JSON data as requested to reflect what I get from the server.

Comment: Can you debug the raw API query? That is, what is the output of `console.log(data)` in the first line of your `success` function? Even better, what is the raw output of a direct request to the API URL though a browser, Postman, Fiddler, etc.?

Comment: Thanks Drew Gaynor, I just revised the raw JSON data I get from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `console.log(team)` is always 3 because when you call `Object.keys(results[1]).length` you are just finding the number of properties (keys) in the first result object (from your sample JSON data).

```
{
    "__metadata":
    {
        "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(53)",
        "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(53)",
        "etag": "18",
        "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
    },
    "Team": "Team A",
    "taskStatus": "Open"
}
```

A simple loop over the results can group them:

```
var results = data.d.results;
var openCount = results.length;
var groupedResults = {};

//Total number of open tasks
console.log(openCount);

for (var i = 0; i < openCount; i++) {
    var team = results[i]["Team"]

    if (!groupedResults[team]) {
        groupedResults[team] = [];
    }

    groupedResults[team].push(results[i]);
}

//Open tasks grouped by team
console.log(groupedResults);

//Count of open tasks for "Team B"
console.log(groupedResults["Team B"].length);
```

See the code snippet below for a fully functional demo based using your sample data.

```js
var data = {
    "d":
    {
        "results":
        [
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(53)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(53)",
                    "etag": "18",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team A",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            },
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(54)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(54)",
                    "etag": "97",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team B",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            },
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(82)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(82)",
                    "etag": "65",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team B",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            },
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(97)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(97)",
                    "etag": "18",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team C",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            },
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(99)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(99)",
                    "etag": "8",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team E",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            },
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'1234578785596655')/Items(106)",
                    "uri": "https://spteamsite.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items(106)",
                    "etag": "44",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
                },
                "Team": "Team D",
                "taskStatus": "Open"
            }
        ]
    }
};

function printResult(value) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  
  d.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(value);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  console.log(value);
}

var results = data.d.results;
var openCount = results.length;
var groupedResults = {};

//Total number of open tasks
printResult("Open tasks for all teams: " + openCount);

for (var i = 0; i < openCount; i++) {
    var team = results[i]["Team"]
    
 if (!groupedResults[team]) {
        groupedResults[team] = [];
    }
    
    groupedResults[team].push(results[i]);
}

//Open tasks grouped by team
printResult(groupedResults);

//Count of open tasks for "Team B"
printResult("Open tasks for Team B: " + groupedResults["Team B"].length);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked as explained. What I really need is to make  groupedResults = {} to be an array instead of an object so that I get a result like so: groupedResults : ["Team A": 1, "Team B": 2, "Team C": 1].

Comment: @Manou What's in your comment is not valid JavaScript. Can you not just iterate through the properties of `groupedResults` with a `for ... in` loop and get the length of each array?

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I need the above format for Google Visualization API to build a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to group by Team then get sum of open.
Using [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com) it is easy

```
var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy("$.Team", null,function (key, g) {
                 return {
                   Team: key,
                   Open: g.Sum("$.Open")                     
                 }
    }).ToArray();
```

### Edited

```
var query = Enumerable.From(jsonObject)
    .GroupBy(
        "$.City",
        null,
        "{ City: $, Count: $$.Count() }").ToArray()
```

Comment: Hello Developer, when I used linq I am able to get the grouping but the sum is not working. I am getting the following result: "0OpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpenOpen". It's only getting the string values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your column/key name for Open?

Comment: var query = Enumerable.From(jsonObject)
    .GroupBy(
        "$.Team",
        null,
        "{ Team: $, Count: $$.Count() }") 
    .ToArray()